# Event handler with AjaxChosen

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, jquery-chosen

I'm trying to use this jquery plugin: https://github.com/meltingice/ajax-chosen
I have a multiple select and I would like to know which event is called when someone deletes a value or when someone choses a value.

Here's what I've done:

```
$("#firmsSelect").ajaxChosen({.....}).change( function (event) {
 console.log($(event.currentTarget));
})
```

I would like to know what can I do whith the currentTarget object. (I tried .val() but the valueI get is for the entire select , aka an array, whereas I just want the value of the element that was deleted/selected.

Comment: Firstly, you have a typo here, it's [`event.currentTarget`](http://api.jquery.com/event.currentTarget/) actually. Not caps `CurrentTarget`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. First I solved it with something like the following code:

```
$("#mySelect").chosen().change(function (event, params) {
 //...
})
```

then you can use:

```
var selectedValue = params.selected;
```

But this does not solve everything, for example when you deselect then property `selected` is undefined, so you can't get the value of the item that has just been deselected.

Eventually I used something like:

```
var options = $(evt.currentTarget).find('option');
```

The array "options" contains all your `<options>` tags within the `<select>` tag. You can then iterate over the items and, with some bookkeeping, know the item that has been deselected.

I hope this helps.